# org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector method executeSB (Galaxy S5)

Tags: java, android, apache, http, httpclient

I'm overriding DefaultHttpClient, and pass my Cache mechanism as a RequestInterceptor and ResponseInterceptor

```
new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry), params) {

        @Override
        protected HttpRequestExecutor createRequestExecutor(){
            return cache == null ? super.createRequestExecutor() : cache.createRequestExecutor();
        }

        @Override
        protected BasicHttpProcessor createHttpProcessor() {
            BasicHttpProcessor processor = super.createHttpProcessor();
            if(null != cache){
                processor.addRequestInterceptor(cache);
                processor.addResponseInterceptor(cache);
            }
            return processor;
        }

        @Override
        protected HttpContext createHttpContext() {
            // Same as DefaultHttpClient.createHttpContext() minus the
            // cookie store.
            HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
            context.setAttribute(
                    ClientContext.AUTHSCHEME_REGISTRY,
                    getAuthSchemes());
            context.setAttribute(
                    ClientContext.COOKIESPEC_REGISTRY,
                    getCookieSpecs());
            context.setAttribute(
                    ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER,
                    getCredentialsProvider());
            return context;
        }
    };
}
```

Then I process Response:

```
private void processResponse(String requestLine, CachedItem item, HttpResponse response, HttpContext context){
    ... some code
                switch(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()){
                    case HttpStatus.SC_NOT_MODIFIED:
                        Log.v(TAG, "processResponse, not modified");
                        updateResponseWithCachedFile(response);
                        break;
                    case HttpStatus.SC_OK:
                        Log.v(TAG, "processResponse, updating cache");
                        saveEntity(response);
                        break;
                }
     ...some code
    }

public synchronized void updateResponseWithCachedFile(HttpResponse response){
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
        response.setEntity(new FileEntity(new File(mCachedFilePath), "" /* it is internal, not used */));
    }

public synchronized void saveEntity(final HttpResponse response){
        try{
            File cacheFile = new File(mCachedFilePath);
            Utils.delete(TAG + " removing obsolete file", cacheFile);
            if(Logger.assertIfFalse(cacheFile.createNewFile(), TAG, "failed to create file " + cacheFile)){
                Files.copy(new InputSupplier<InputStream>() {
                    @Override
                    public InputStream getInput() throws IOException{
                        return response.getEntity().getContent();
                    }
                }, cacheFile);
            }


        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        updateResponseWithCachedFile(response);
    }
```

My problem is on the Galaxy s5.
I get an Exception:

> 07-29 21:00:57.227 28164 29824 W System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity cannot be cast to org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
>   07-29 21:00:57.227 28164 29824 W System.err:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeSB(DefaultRequestDirector.java:880)
>   07-29 21:00:57.227 28164 29824 W System.err:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:675)
>   07-29 21:00:57.227 28164 29824 W System.err:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:567)
>   07-29 21:00:57.227 28164 29824 W System.err:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:491)
>   07-29 21:00:57.227 28164 29824 W System.err:    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:469)
>   07-29 21:00:57.227 28164 29824 W System.err:    at com.my_application.service.background.HttpRequest$1.run(HttpRequest.java:138)
>   07-29 21:00:57.227 28164 29824 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   07-29 21:00:57.227 28164 29824 W System.err:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   07-29 21:00:57.227 28164 29824 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

and here i see a method:
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeSB(DefaultRequestDirector.java:880)

I didn't found anything about this. 
Maybe Samsung has it's own implementations of this classes?
I Don't have S5 to run this on the device.
Why do I get this error?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you and I doubt you are still looking for help after all this time but maybe someone else will find this useful. I have found that Apache HTTP does not seem to be very reliable on S5's specifically Verizon S5's. I encountered this problem while trying to use Restlet clients on an Android application to connect to a JSON server. I continually would receive a connection error to the local host as odd as that was since I was attempting to connect to a remote server.

A long process of trial and error led me to believe that Samsung is overriding or providing their own implementation of Apache HTTP at a low level as using the Restlet internal connector and providing no other changes resolves the issue. It appears to be tied into some software update because a factory reset will allow Apache HTTP to work for a short amount of time before stop working again. It would be interesting to see if anyone else encounters this issue.